# char array length c++ <i'm newcomer>

Tags: c++

i'm newcomer.
i need size of input.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int a,b,n;
    char c[100];
    cout<<"insert number of adjective :  " ;
    cin>>a;
    for(b=0;b<a;b++)
    {
        cin>>c;
        int length = sizeof(c);
        cout<<length<<endl;
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please help me for find the size lenght c

---

hamed

Comment: You want strlen if your forced to use cstrings instead of C++ std::string.

Comment: You should really look up `std::string`.

Comment: but i Should not use string

Comment: I assume  that means you can not use `std::string` because of a homework assignment. Look up strlen() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

Comment: When you're not doing homework, the answer is `std::getline` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline ).  Also, you may want to reconsider learning C++ from somebody who lets you use iostreams but doesn't want you using `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use vector

```
#include <vector> ...
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> vec(n);
...
int size_of_vector = vec.size();
...
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, *never* (as in really **never**) use `std::cin >> array;` wher e `array` is a `char` array (or a pointer to the start of such an arry) *unless* you have first set up the maximum amount of data which can be read by setting the stream's `width()`. Any teacher showing you how to use `std::cin >> array;` without advising to use `width()` *has to be corrected*!

You can, e.g., use

```
#include <cstring> // NOT <string>...
// ...
char c[100];
std::cin.width(sizeof(c));
if (std::cin >> c) {
    std::size_t n = std::strlen(c);
    // ...
}
```

to limit the number of character to be read to `sizeof(c) - 1` (the `-1` is there because a terminating null character is also read). Once you have successfully read your input (you also need to *always* check that input was actually successful) you can use `strlen(c)` to determine the number of characters read.

Personally, I read *very* rarely formatted data into a `char` array in real code. I normally simply read a `std::string` which is much easier and safer to use. I'd consider dealing with input to built-in array a somewhat more advanced topic.

Answer (score -1):

```html
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 ////////////////////input
 int a,b,n,i;
 char c[100];
 cout<<"insert number of adjective :  " ;
 cin>>a;
 for(b=0;b<a;b++)
 {
  cin>>c;
        n = strlen(c) ;
  cout<<n<<endl;
  /////////////////////////processing
  if(c[n]=='r')
  {
    cout<<"ok";
  }
  /////////////////////////output
  cout<<c<<endl;
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This map help then.

```
/* strlen example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szInput[256];
  printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
  gets (szInput);
  printf ("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n",(unsigned)strlen(szInput));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: gets :/ And strlens result is already unsigned (but maybe a different type, so you have another problem)

Comment: `gets()` is removed from C11 and from C++14. It is essentially an approach to break any program.

Answer (score -3):

1. first use: `#include <string>`
2. second write: `int length = strlen(c); // insted of  int length = sizeof(c);`

`strlen()` function find length of string but you must include string library.